# Baking AO: Certain region is black

Tags: texturing, texture-baking, ambient-occlusion

When baking AO to this piece, a certain region is black. I tried using the "select non-manifold", "merge by distance" and Recalculate options but nothing resulted. Any idea of what could possibly be causing this issue?
[image]